# How to create two instances of statically linked library, with different defines?

Tags: c, macros, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a C library that uses a define macro to determine the logic of some of its code. What would be the best way to create two instances of this library, each with a different value of the macro?

To clarify, the code looks something like this:

```
#if (MY_VAR == VAL1)
    ... do stuff
#else
    ... do other stuff
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is compile two deferent libraries with diferent names.